# How to fix .htaccess issues in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My domain base URL working fine and when I move to next level they show error page not found.

I already try settings->permalinks->custom post and also try another option page id work fine and post name gives an error.

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 127:25:156 Port 80

Comment: Does it work when you use plain ("ugly") permalinks? For example `yourdomain.com/?p=123`

Comment: What is file structure? I mean base URL has WP setup and you create another folder and clone the WP into it?

Comment: "when I move to next level" - Do you mean when you move the WordPress installation into a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make following changes in .htaccess file of your sub folder setup.

If your base URL is www.example.com and in .htaccess file it has code like

```
RewriteBase /
```

Change it by

```
RewriteBase /youfoldername/
```

and change following line

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule . /youfoldername/index.php [L]
```

Comment: The whole point of the `RewriteBase` directive is so that you don't have to do this: `RewriteRule . /youfoldername/index.php [L]`. (Although the _default_ WordPress code block does not help with this confusion.)